# How can I save HTML content in SQLite Database

Tags: android, json, database, wordpress, sqlite

How can we save a JSON adapted WordPress posts with links, images, in a way that is accessible offline?

There is no problem for save plain text and thumbnail images, but how can we save images that are among texts?

> Here is an idea: we could make an algorithm to reverse values between <img> so we can download the image, then address the device memory so that when it is read from the database, texts and images will be shown properly

What's the best way to save an HTML file content completely and thoroughly?

For example, I have this string:

```
<p> Text 1 </p> <img src="www.test.com/1.jpg" >
<p> Text 2 </p> <img src="www.mydomain.com/2.jpg" >
```

and I want save it into SQLite like this :

```
<p> Text 1 </p> <img src= myDir + "/1.jpg" >
<p> Text 2 </p> <img src= myDir + "/2.jpg" >
```

What's your idea about pattern?

Comment: I had same issue. And I solved it this way - I parsed html for images, I saved images locally and I edited html - replacing external links with internal.

Comment: OK , How can find images and change Src of images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a local server like XAMPP? So you could just copy site as is and it will work offline.

Comment: The answer doesn't answer OP question, it's a workaround.